# Python RSA message encryption "Plaintext is too long"?

Tags: python, rsa

I'm using the following code to implement a basic RSA solution for encrypting and decrypting data, but when I try to encrypt any text that is longer than 87 characters I get an error saying `Plaintext is too long` from the file `Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py`.

I read on other questions that RSA cannot encrypt and decrypt large sets of data but I'm not sure if that's true. If it is, what other options can I use to encrypt any amount of data?

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA512, SHA384, SHA256, SHA, MD5
from Crypto import Random
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
hash = "SHA-256"

def newkeys(keysize):
   random_generator = Random.new().read
   key = RSA.generate(keysize, random_generator)
   private, public = key, key.publickey()
   return public, private

def encrypt(message, pub_key):
   cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pub_key)
   return cipher.encrypt(message)
```

Comment: you could have a read at some suggestions given here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50033/what-will-happen-if-i-use-rsa-encryption-for-plaintext-larger-than-rsa-bit-size.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia Thanks for pointing the obvious, do you understand any of the solutions presented in that question? well, neither do I.

Comment: RSA can encrypt a plaintext only up to the key length,e.g.with a RSA 2048 key = 2048 bit = 256 byte) you can encrypt 256 bytes **minus** the data needed for the internal padding so in the end you can encrypt just around some hundreds of byte plaintext (depending on the key length). The solution to encrypt longer plaintext is to use **hybrid encryption**, that means you encrypt the data with a **symmetric** algorithm like AES in GCM mode and use a randomly generated key (32 bytes long). In a second step you encrypt this key with your RSA public key. For decryption - first RSA than AES.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it like this : [This is on my code i havent edited yours]

```
    with open(file, 'rb') as f: 
        fernet_key = f.read() 
        if len(fernet_key) > 80 : 
            fernet_key1 = ''
            tostart = 0
            toadd = 0
            flag_tostart = 0
            while True: 
                if fernet_key1 == fernet_key: 
                    break
                else:
                    flag_tostart = flag_tostart +1
                    if flag_tostart == '2'or flag_tostart > 2 or flag_tostart == 2: 
                        tostart = tostart + 80


                    toadd = toadd +80
                    
                    if tostart == 0 : 
                        tostart = 0 
                    
                    else:   
                        tostart = tostart + 80

                    fernet_key[tostart:toadd] += fernet_key1

                    public_crypter = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)

                    with open(file, 'wb') as f: 
                        enc_fernet_key = 
                        public_crypter.encrypt(fernet_key1)

                        f.write(enc_fernet_key)
```